# Change date in slides for every quarter

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint, with a few title Slides. I would like to know if it is possible to change the date automatically in the slides to reference the year and quarter.

So for Example in June it should say 2018 Q2.

Can it be done in VBA for PowerPoint?

Comment: Where in the slides is this text ("2018 Q2")?  In a text box? a footer? in many different shapes? Charts?

Answer (score 0):

Here is VBA to change the SlideMaster footer to your year/quater format

```
Sub FormatSlideMasterFooter()

ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = Format(Now(), "yyyy") & " L" & Int(Month(Now()) / 4) + 1


End Sub
```